# How to check if an Android app started by a service in a separate Android app has finished loading?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle

I am using the code below to start an installed camera app (not developed by me) from a background service in an app I'm working on.

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sec.android.app.camera");
startActivity( launchIntent );
```

**I need to determine if the camera app is done loading and ready to use** so I can prompt the camera to take a picture. After the picture is taken, *my app* will be brought back to the foreground and show a screensaver until the camera is started again or brought back to the foreground to take another picture. Is there a way to verify that the camera app is loaded and ready each time before attempting to send it commands?

For clarity, I'm not asking about how to check this on a camera app specifically. I'm trying to learn how I can start just about any app (not developed by me) and listen for it to be completely loaded and ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using the code below to start an installed camera app (not developed by me) from a background service

Launching activities from the background is not supported on modern versions of Android.

Also note that many devices will not have that particular package.

> I need to determine if the camera app is done loading and ready to use so I can prompt the camera to take a picture

There is no canonical definition of "done loading and ready to use". And, in general, there is no means for you to monitor the operations of another app, for privacy and security reasons.

Also, outside of accessibility services, in general, you have no means of telling a running app to do anything unless it has a specific API for that purpose. Even with accessibility services, I suspect that it will be difficult to come up with an approach that works no matter what the camera app is.

If, from the foreground, you want a camera app to take a picture, use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Or, integrate camera functionality directly in your own app, such as via CameraX or other libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your input. After considering the alternatives, I think trying to integrate camera functionality will be the best solution in this case.